# How to display a Postgres aliased field in Vaadin field?

Tags: java, jooq, postgresql-9.1, vaadin7

This is a query I wrote:

```
public List<PrRevamps> fetchRevampHistory(String refNo) {
    List<PrRevamps> list = dsl.select(
            DSL.concat(
                Tables.PR_REVAMPS.PR_REVAMP_CODE,DSL.val("-"),
                Tables.PR_REVAMP_CODES.PR_DESCRIPTION
            ).as("DESCRIPTION"),
            Tables.PR_REVAMPS.PR_REVAMP_DATE,
            Tables.PR_REVAMPS.PR_KEY)
        .from(Tables.PR_REVAMP_CODES,Tables.PR_REVAMPS)
        .where(Tables.PR_REVAMPS.PR_REVAMP_CODE.equal(Tables.PR_REVAMP_CODES.PR_CODE))
        .and(Tables.PR_REVAMPS.PR_PROP_REF_NO.equal(refNo))
        .fetchInto(PrRevamps.class);
    
    return list;
}
```

and I need to display revampCode and description in one row in vaadin grid.
i.e "A-Marshall"

This is the grid code below:

```
private void populateRevampGrid() {
    Object ref = serv.getAttribute("ref");
    String propRef = "";
    
    if(ref != null) {
        propRef = (String)ref;
        
        List<PrRevamps> list = getService().fetchRevampHistory(propRef);
        
        if(!list.isEmpty()) {
            revampGrid.setContainerDataSource(new BeanItemContainer<>(list));
            //revampGrid.addColumn("prRevampCode").setHeaderCaption("REVAMP DESCRIPTION");
            revampGrid.removeColumn("prKey");
            revampGrid.removeColumn("prLeaseType");
            revampGrid.removeColumn("prPropRefNo");
            revampGrid.getColumn("prRevampDate").setHeaderCaption("REVAMP DATE");
            revampGrid.getColumn("prRevampCode").setHeaderCaption("REVAMP TYPE");
        } else {
            clearfields();
            Notification.show("list is empty",Type.ERROR_MESSAGE.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1  is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: How do i display the concatenated fields(from the query) in vaadin grid @Lukas Eder, That's my question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have the description field, that has the desired value.

If not, you can add properties, generated from an object on the fly. But for this, you will need to use Container.

The full description can be found on Vaadin documentation https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/datamodel/datamodel-container.html (see GeneratedPropertyContainer)